# How do I configure QGIS Web Client on Ubuntu/Debian for remote access

Tags: qgis-server, qgis-web-client

I am having issues with accessing the QGIS Web Client on a remote web browser despite getting a working GetCapabilities request.

I have been able to install QGIS Server and QGIS Web Client on the localhost with success using Ubuntu/Debian. As a result, on the local server, I am able to open up a web browser and go to the url: qgis-web-client.localhost and access the default client landing page and open up the local maps, helloworld and naturalearth_110million, with success. Further, I am able to insert new QGIS project files into the same folder where helloworld and naturalearth_110million reside and update the client landing page with success on the localhost.

However, when it comes to a remote browser, I am not able to access the client landing page with all of the created QGIS projects.

I have tried a few different combinations for the installation of QGIS Web Client to enable the remote web browser to no avail:
1. I installed QGIS Web Client on my local directory "/home/johndoe" by performing "git clone https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client.git" and then entering in "sudo ./install.sh ~/qgis-web-client/projects"
2. On a separate server machine, I also attempted to install QGIS Web Client on my the directory "/var/www/html" by performing "git clone https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client.git" and then entering in "sudo ./install.sh /var/www/html/qgis-web-client/projects"

Are there any tips for configuring QGIS Web Client via Ubuntu/Debian so that a remote web browser may access the data accordingly?

Comment: I've got my QGIS Web Client working (except for search) on Ubuntu from a remote browser. I've put my web client site in my /var/www/html/qwc/site folder. When I remotely type in my URL: http://yourdomainname.com/qwc/site/index.html I see something. Also double check your permissions on your site folder. Are you able to see anything at all when you even load the index.html page?

Comment: not very familiar with the app, but on ubuntu/debian you could try `sudo netstat -taupen` and see if it's listening for remote connections

Comment: Hi Jan, I am able to see the QGIS Web Client landing page when I remotely type in my URL. However, the only links shown on the "Your local maps" on the URL are only those of "HelloWorld" and "NaturalEarth" while I expect to see additional maps that I may see on the local browser's QGIS Web Client landing page under "qgis-web-client.localhost". Furthermore, clicking on the HelloWorld and NaturalEarth links on the remote browser takes me to the GIS Web Browser page with a hanging "Loading map application..." message.

Comment: Hi wchatx, I checked "sudo netstat -taupen" and do confirm that the associated IP address whereby I should expect to access the web server is "established". Any other thoughts for getting the configuration to work?

Comment: When you say you're able to get the "GetCapabilities" request working, is it giving you the GetCapabilities of a particular project you've created (or the hello world project) ? You'll know because if you created a project, say one qgs project with one shapefile, and you correctly loaded that shapefile and project into your Apache directory structure (use relative links option in associated QGIS project -> Project -> Project Properties-> Save Paths "relative") or your user directory, you should be able to get a GetCapabilities request result that includes information on that shapefile.

Comment: Furthermore, what does Firefox Firebug give you as the error when you try to load the Helloworld project URL from the landing page?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to subsequently resolve my issue with accessing the default client landing page remotely. I simply needed to perform the following steps:

1. edit the qgis-web-client.conf file by inserting a "ServerAlias" for the ServerName qgis-web-client.localhost
   1a. enter in the following under ServerName qgis-web-client.localhost: "ServerAlias qgismaps"
2. edit the /etc/hosts file of the local server
   2a. enter in the following: "127.0.0.1 qgismaps"
3. restart apache2 via "sudo service apache2 restart"
4. edit the host file of the remote machine
   4a. enter in the following: " qgismaps"
   If the IP address of the local server is "12.345.67.890", then modify the remote machine's host file with the following: "12.345.67.890 qgismaps"

Now, on the remote machine, you should be able to open up a browser and connect to the default client landing page by entering in the URL "qgismaps"